# Installed NuGet throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Creating classlibrary and trying to install `Markdig`.

[image]

I can use usings in code, but I'm trying to start debugging and it throws it:

[image]

link to library.
https://github.com/xoofx/markdig

Here is my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Kvyk.Telegraph.Markdown</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Kvyk.Telegraph" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Markdig" Version="0.25.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You should post this under [issues](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/issues) in the GitHub repository.

Comment: @KarenPayne https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/issues/558

Comment: That is correct

Comment: The command-line solution works fine for me.

`dotnet add package Markdig --version 0.25.0` and
`dotnet restore`

You tried that?